# browse file path spring webflow

Tags: forms, spring, jsf, input

I am currently working on a spring webflow application. In this project there are certain entities that point to a document that contains more information about that entity. However sometimes this document is not provided. In that case the user must be able to research the file for himself.

I need a simple way to let the user search a file and then save the filepath of the selected file into the database.

For most of our components we use richfaces but I don't really like the richfaces `<fileUpload>` because it's too big and too complex. I have seen that icefaces and tomahawk provide nice solutions but our application is limited to richfaces. 
I thought of just using the normal:

`<form:form> <input type="file> </form:form>"`

but I don't know how I can get the information from that submitted form into my bean. I hoped that I could trigger an event once the file had been selected and then use a  listener in my bean that would read the filename from the event. However I cannot find the syntax to do this (I don't even know if this is possible).

Can anyone help me? I know I can just do it with richfaces but I don't think that the client would like that enormous form to just select a filepath

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a simple jsp file upload?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

Comment: I would like to use the normaly file upload but I don't know how I can get the information into my bean.